# How to wrap showModalBottomSheet in SafeArea? - Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am using a textformfield in the bottomsheet, when the keyboard is opened, the sheet is going out of safe Area, is there anyway we can wrap bottomsheet in safeArea? I tried wrapping the bottomsheet child into safeArea, but it didn't work.

**When the keyboard closed:**

[image: keyboard closed]

***Code:***

```
onPressed: () {
                showModalBottomSheet(
                            isScrollControlled: true,
                            context: context,
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                    topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                                    topRight: Radius.circular(10))),
                            builder: (context) {
                              return Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                    bottom: MediaQuery.of(context)
                                        .viewInsets
                                        .bottom),
                                child: Container(
                                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                                        top: MediaQuery.of(context)
                                            .viewPadding
                                            .top),
                                    height:
                                        MediaQuery.of(context).size.height *
                                            0.65,
                                    child:
                                        SinglePostScreen(postID: posts.id)),
                            );
                        });
                      }
```

**The screen that displays in bottomsheet (while keyboard opened):**

[image: while keyboard opened]

***Code:***

```
class SinglePostScreen extends StatefulWidget {
final String postID;

SinglePostScreen({@required this.postID});

@override
_SinglePostScreenState createState() => _SinglePostScreenState();
}

class _SinglePostScreenState extends State<SinglePostScreen> {
final ConstantColors constantColors = ConstantColors();
Future<SinglePost> singlePost;
Future<UserProfileModel> userProfileModel;
TextEditingController commentCont = TextEditingController();
 @override
void initState() {
super.initState();
singlePost = SinglePostServices().singlePost(widget.postID);
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return SafeArea(
  child: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: Radius.circular(10), topRight: Radius.circular(10))),
      child: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Divider(
              color: Colors.black45,
              thickness: 2.5,
              indent: 150,
              endIndent: 150,
            ),
            Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.55,
              child: FutureBuilder<SinglePost>(
                future: singlePost,
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                    return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                  }
                  if (snapshot.data.comments.length == 0) {
                    return Text(
                      "no data yet",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                    );
                  }
                  if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                    return Container(
                      child: ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: snapshot.data.comments.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            var comments = snapshot.data.comments[index];
                            return Container(
                              child: Column(
                                children: [
                                  FutureBuilder<UserProfileModel>(
                                    future: userProfileModel =
                                        UserProfileServices()
                                            .getUserProfile(
                                                comments.userId),
                                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                                      if (snapshot.hasData) {
                                        return Provider.of<
                                                    SinglePageHelpers>(
                                                context,
                                                listen: false)
                                            .comment(
                                                context,
                                                "https://source.unsplash.com/random",
                                                "${snapshot.data.firstname} ${snapshot.data.lastname}",
                                                timeago.format(comments
                                                    .createdAt
                                                    .toLocal()),
                                                comments.comment);
                                      } else {
                                        return Center(
                                            child:
                                                CircularProgressIndicator());
                                      }
                                    },
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            );
                          }),
                    );
                  }
                },
              ),
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                  child: Container(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.7,
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.06,
                    child: TextFormField(
                      maxLines: 5,
                      minLines: 1,
                      cursorHeight: 15,
                      cursorColor: constantColors.purple,
                      cursorWidth: 1,
                      controller: commentCont,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          hintText: "add comment",
                          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          hintStyle:
                              TextStyle(color: Colors.black, height: 1.4),
                          fillColor: Colors.grey[200],
                          filled: true,
                          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                              borderSide: BorderSide(
                                color: Colors.transparent,
                              )),
                          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                              borderSide: BorderSide(
                                color: Colors.transparent,
                              ))),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                RawMaterialButton(
                  fillColor: constantColors.purple,
                  constraints: BoxConstraints.tight(Size(75, 35)),
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: Text(
                    "comment",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
   ),
  );
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call the method `showModalBottomSheet(useSafeArea: true)`
in the bottom padding you can use padding for example:

```
EdgeInsets.only(
  bottom: MediaQuery.of(context)
    .viewInsets
    .bottom + 20,
)
```

Also you can use LimitedBox like:

```
LimitedBox(
  maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - AppBar().preferredSize.height,
  child: Column(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
    children: [],
  ),
),
```